# How to add Summary Field in RDLC report?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using RDLC report in Win-form. I want to add the Below Page as Summary. That's mean, I want to add this page as separate page in Report.

My Friends Working in Fox pro. He said it possible in Summary Field, Its Like a Footer. But Can't able to Find That. Pls Help Me.

```
              The Committee has considered the following aspects before finalizing the attendance%      
    for the B.Sc H&HA I year I semester Students,   

           1.    Students involved in attending ODC, Exhibitions and other functions        
        deputed by the college.

          2.    Students who had shortage of attendance were instructed to attend the classes in        
         the weekend / Holidays. Classes were conducted by the staff who 
        were stationed at the Institute.

                 As directed by the principal, in the interest of the students and due to the semester pattern,                                     
    It has been decided to consider overall attendance % for the eligibility to write                               
    the NCHM semester examination 2011. 


(Mr.Elangovan)   (Mr.Mathew)    (Mr. Senthil Kumar)      (Ms. Sharmila)     ( Ms. Parimala)    (Mr. Thirulogchander)                                                





                            (PRINCIPAL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to add a page break before your summary text:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251701(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, Foxpro makes things like that very easy...  Not knowing your data source, and if you could adjust by adding a column/field to the output per row.  I would add a column of a blob (or Memo from FoxPro) where you can just dump a bunch of text to it.  Then on the last record of the data to be printed, have this column printed.  Since it won't exist for any previous records, it wont otherwise cause a conflict with any other content.  Then, as Daniel mentioned, you can throw a force page break so this content shows on its own page.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it will probably be easier to add a page break to your report and add your info page above to that page. I don't know what you are using to create your report Visual Studio 2005/2008 but here are some instructions on adding a page break in VS 2005.

[How to Set Page Breaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251733%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Defining Page Size and Page Breaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251701%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I am not sure of how your report is set up but if you instructions do specify the following:

```
To add a page break to a report item
Right-click the report item and then click Properties.

**Note**
Item page breaks apply only to the report items rectangle, table, matrix, list, and chart.
On the General tab, for Page breaks, select Insert a page break before this list (rectangle, table, or matrix) or Insert a page break after this list (rectangle, table, or matrix).
```

So keep in mind that applying the page break to an item it has to be a rectangle, table, etc.  I just did a test in VS2005 and added a rectangle, then placed a text box inside with the data from above and it placed it on a separate page in the report.

Hope this helps.